# En "sirva de impedimento", ¿cuál es el sujeto de "sirva"?

Tags: sujeto

[embargo | Definición | Diccionario de la lengua española | RAE - ASALE](https://dle.rae.es/embargo#1Zo0amT)

> #### sin embargo
>
> 1. loc. adv. Sin que **sirva** de impedimento. *Resulta verosímil y, sin embargo, hay que ponerlo en duda. Jugó bien, pero no logró ganar, sin embargo.*

¿Qué o quien  exactamente  "**sirva** de impedimento"? ¿O es servir un verbo impersonal aquí?

Answer (score 1):

El sujeto de **sirva** en "sin que sirva de impedimento" es el hecho o la situación que se han descrito antes. Por ejemplo, la frase

> Resulta verosímil y, sin embargo, hay que ponerlo en duda

se puede reformular así:

- Resulta verosímil. Sin que **esto** sirva de impedimento, hay que ponerlo en duda

donde el sujeto **esto** es un pronombre que se refiere al hecho de que "resulta verosímil". Otro ejemplo:

- Es muy simpático. Sin embargo, le cuesta hacer amigos.
- Es muy simpático. Sin que **esto** sirva de impedimento, le cuesta hacer amigos

donde, de nuevo, el sujeto **esto** se refiere al hecho de que "es muy simpático".

He de decir, sin embargo, que las frases con "sin que sirva de impedimento" son muy forzadas y no creo que se usen en la lengua oral o escrita. Mucho más natural sería:

- Resulta verosímil. Esto no impide que haya que ponerlo en duda

y aún más natural es, por supuesto, usar *sin embargo* o *no obstante*.